# EF Core: Define foreign key for part of a composite PK using a chained property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have the following model:

```
internal class SchemaEfEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DatabaseEfEntity Database { get; set; }
}

internal class DatabaseEfEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public InstanceEfEntity Instance { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SchemaEfEntity> Schemas { get; set; }
}

internal class InstanceEfEntity : IEfIdEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DatabaseEfEntity> Databases { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
        internal DbSet<InstanceEfEntity> Instances { get; set; }
        internal DbSet<DatabaseEfEntity> Databases { get; set; }
        internal DbSet<SchemaEfEntity> Schemas { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<InstanceEfEntity>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InstanceEfEntity>().HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<DatabaseEfEntity>().HasKey(
                $"{nameof(DatabaseEfEntity.Instance)}{nameof(InstanceEfEntity.Id)}",
                $"{nameof(DatabaseEfEntity.Name)}");

            modelBuilder.Entity<SchemaEfEntity>().HasKey(
                $"{nameof(SchemaEfEntity.Database)}{nameof(DatabaseEfEntity.Instance)}{nameof(InstanceEfEntity.Id)}",
                $"{nameof(SchemaEfEntity.Database)}{nameof(DatabaseEfEntity.Name)}",
                $"{nameof(SchemaEfEntity.Name)}");
        }
}
```

The `SchemaEfEntity` has a composite PK defined that consists of (`InstanceId`, `DatabaseName` and `SchemaName`).

I'd like to define a foreign key from `schema.InstanceId` to `instance.Id`.
I've tried this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<SchemaEfEntity>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Database.Instance)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(
                $"{nameof(SchemaEfEntity.Database)}{nameof(DatabaseEfEntity.Instance)}{nameof(InstanceEfEntity.Id)}"
            );
```

But getting the below error when creating a migration:

> The expression 'c => c.Database.Instance' is not a valid property
>   expression. The expression should represent a simple property access:
>   't => t.MyProperty'. Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

Any ideas? Is it possible at all? Is there a way to specify it "by hand", i.e. not using the properties chain but just specifying the table and a column as a plain text?

Comment: It seems weird that you're saying a Schema has a Database and a Database has an Instance, but you want Schema's relationship to Instance to be defined by its InstanceId. Shouldn't Schema have an Instance property, in that case?

Comment: Please notice how composite primary keys are defined. Basically, the Schema entity has the InstanceId property anyway thanks to its relationship to the Database. Looking at the Schema table in the database, it has the following columns: InstanceId, DatabaseName, Name - so I don't see a reason why it can't be done in EF Core.

Comment: I'd still say if Schema has an InstanceId property, `SchemaEfEntity` should probably have an `Instance` navigation property, don't you think?

Comment: Not really, because when you have a SchemaEfEntity object initialized, you can access InstanceId by: `schema.Database.Instance.Id`, so there is no need for an additional `schema.InstanceId` IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the following syntax:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SchemaEfEntity>()
    .HasOne(typeof(InstanceEfEntity))
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(
        $"{nameof(SchemaEfEntity.Database)}{nameof(DatabaseEfEntity.Instance)}{nameof(InstanceEfEntity.Id)}")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```